# Mass upload pictures for performance testing

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql

To test performance with many and large binary objects, I need 1.000 or more document attachments to be available within Exact Online.

Loading them through the user interface is quite cumbersome: many clicks per document and there is no easy drag & drop. Email might be an option, but still with 1.000 documents it is a hassle.

How can I fast load a large volume of document attachments into Exact Online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way was to use the website [lorempixel.com](http://lorempixel.com). On every unique hit it provides a new nice picture with configurable dimensions (throughput is approximately 1000 KB of document attachments created per second).

```
set use-http-cache false 

use 868056 /* Set division. */

insert into exactonlinerest..documents
( subject
, type 
)
select 'Sample document #' || value
,      101
from   range(1000)@datadictionary /* Load 1,000 documents. */


insert into exactonlinerest..DocumentAttachmentFiles 
( attachment
, document
, filename
)
/* And each document gets an additional attachment per time this insert is run. Run it 10 times to load 10 document attachments per document. */
select httpget('http://lorempixel.com/400/400/?val=' || value) attachment
,      dct.id
,      value || '.jpg'
from   range(1000, 1)@datadictionary
join   exactonlinerest..documents dct
on     dct.type = 101 
and    dct.subject like 'Sample document #%'
and    dct.subject = 'Sample document #' || value
```